# Assign Data Model to View Controller in appDelegate with Storyboards - ios

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, appdelegate

Without `Storyboards` I used to assign the `Data Model` to the `View Controller` with this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of **AppDelegate**:

```
//Data Model Class
DataModel *model=[[DataModel alloc] init];

// TableViewController
Controller *controller=[[Controller alloc] initWithModel:model style:UITableViewStylePlain];

self.window.rootViewController=controller;
```

In **initWithModel** method of the `view Controller`:

```
-(id)initWithModel:(SBQAllReadersModel *) aModel
             style:(UITableViewStyle)    aStyle{

    if (self=[super initWithStyle:aStyle])
    {
        _model=aModel;
    }

    return self;
}
```

But with `Storyboards` I can't do:

```
//Data Model Class
DataModel *model=[[DataModel alloc] init];

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboardstoryboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];

Controller *controller = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Controller"];

controller.model=model;
```

The thing is that in `Storyboards` I can't use the `init` method of the `View Controller` because it isn't recognized for the `Storyboard`. I have to use the `initWithCoder:` which it can't be overriden, and I can't pass parameters to `awakeFromNib`.

What do you recommend me to assign the `data model` with `Storyboards` to the `Controllers` from `appDelegate`?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Given the way the DataModel is allocated, I think a lazy getter in the first view controller is superior (even to your old way of doing it).  e.g.

```
// in Controller.m private interface declare @property(strong,nonatomic) DataModel *dataModel, then...

- (DataModel *)dataModel {
    if (!_dataModel) {
        _dataModel = [[DataModel alloc] init];
    }
    return _dataModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `initWithCoder`: of the `view controller` I allocated the model.

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
    {
        // Do something
        _model=[[DataModel alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Yep its better use the lazy getter you say ;)

So have I to allocate the `model` in the `rootViewControler` and pass the model by `delegation` to the next controller that need to use it?